# Cannot read property 'pop' of undefined || next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[the screen shot of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk4Qn.jpg)        $ npm run build

```
> learn-starter@0.1.0 build
> next build

(node:31220) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at C:\Users\murtu\OneDrive\Desktop\myProject\nextjs_practice\new_practice\nextjs-blog\node_modules\postcss\package.json.       
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
info  - Creating an optimized production build    
Failed to compile.

chunk 30cd56ec8b4292fd1d19f6bfd4b67b1689d06305_CSS
static/css/851b1bf4ba9315e79ff2.css
Cannot read property 'pop' of undefined


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at C:\Users\murtu\OneDrive\Desktop\myProject\nextjs_practice\new_practice\nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:15:918
    at async C:\Users\murtu\OneDrive\Desktop\myProject\nextjs_practice\new_practice\nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\build\tracer.js:1:525
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\murtu\OneDrive\Desktop\myProject\nextjs_practice\new_practice\nextjs-blog
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c next build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\murtu\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-24T13_03_26_358Z-debug.log
```

i am facing this problems since i have tried many solution from internet like creating next.config.js
the project is perfectly working while i am using this a `npm run dev`
can anyone help me here what is the problem here
As i have sayed that project is perfectly working on `npm run dev`.
i am really tired of this problem , please help me out here.

Comment: Did you manage to get past this? Facing the same issue. Not clear what the cause could be.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you didn't mention it in your post, I can see that you are using NextJS. I just ran into this same issue today randomly without really making any changes to our app. The fix I found that worked for us was adding the following to our next.config.js file.

```
// next.config.js

const nextConfig = {
  ... other NextJS configuration values,
  webpack(config) {
    if (config.optimization.splitChunks) {
      config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.shared = {
        name: 'app-other', // this needs to be a value that is different from what the other chunks in your app are using
        test: /\.css$/,
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
      };
    },
    ...the rest of your Webpack config values
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Hopefully, this works for others and saves them some time.

Comment: I just ran into this error seemingly randomly as well. I wish I knew what caused it, but it just started occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when I upgraded node and npm version.
I just deleted package-lock.json and node-modules folder and did npm install. The problem was solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).