# Problem when runing npm run dev in nextJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

After a couple of weeks of not touching this repo, I started to receive this error message when runing npm run dev:

Failed to compile

```
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[7].oneOf[14].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[7].oneOf[14].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[7].oneOf[14].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[7].oneOf[14].use[4]!./styles/style.scss
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pop')

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[7].oneOf[14].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[7].oneOf[14].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[7].oneOf[14].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[7].oneOf[14].use[4]!./styles/style.scss
./styles/style.scss
```

This error occurred during the build process and can only be dismissed by fixing the error.

---

I used this configuration when creating the app:

- Would you like to use TypeScript? No
- Would you like to use ESLint? Yes
- Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? No
- Would you like to use src/ directory? No
- Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) No
- Would you like to customize the default import alias? No
- What import alias would you like configured? @/*

My node version is 21.0.0

I did a lot of things like updating every package and uninstalling and installing again node. But still occurring.

No need to say that I didn't change anything in the style.scss file; anyway, if I remove it from the _app.js file, the problem disappears... but the styles too!

I already tried this: [Cannot read property 'pop' of undefined || next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65438955/cannot-read-property-pop-of-undefined-next-js)

my next.config.js looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    if (config.optimization.splitChunks) {
      config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.shared = {
        name: 'app-other', // this needs to be a value that is different from what the other chunks in your app are using
        test: /\.css$/,
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
      };
    }
    return config

  }
  
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: What is your Node version?

Comment: My node version is 21.0.0

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65438955/cannot-read-property-pop-of-undefined-next-js

Comment: I did it. Not worked for me